# Multiprocessing vs multithreading for mining

Tags: xmrig

Which one is better (higher hash rate)?

1. Multiple xmrig processes with single threads
2. Single xmrig process with multiple threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XMRig is designed to run as a single process with multiple threads – if it were faster the other way round, it would have been changed to run easily that way instead.

In any case, the maximum hashrate possible with either #1 or #2 is likely the same.